# GAE Full Text Search API on datastore entities using Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search

I heard that we have [app engine Search API support for Golang](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/). but it is not clear if we have can use this search API on GAE datastore entities (the [Google IO 2011 video](https://youtu.be/7B7FyU9wW8Y?t=30m5s) says it is possible, but not sure if that is really supported using Golang). Any thoughts about this? and any good documentation with examples? really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run full text search on the datastore entities. To perform full text search you need to create separate Documents in the text search indexes, which is independent from the datastore. If you want to do text search on what data you have in the datastore, iterate over it and create the documents from the entities in full text search indexes.

For documentation , the link you provided

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/

have the information in it.